# You and your rudeness "is" or "are"?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

> You and your rudeness *is* getting on my nerves.
>
> You and your rudeness *are* getting on my nerves.

Answer (score 2):

Verb number agreement dictates use of *are*. Two things (you, and also your rudeness) require the verb form for plurals.

Also, in case you're not aware, saying this is confrontational, so be ready.